# Using Distinct as a parameter

Tags: sql, distinct

```
SELECT ORIGIN_NAME, SUM(NET_WEIGHT),
CASE WHEN ORIGIN_NAME IS NULL THEN 'Basket' ELSE ORIGIN_NAME END AS ORIGIN
FROM VW_PURCHASE_ORDER
GROUP BY ORIGIN_NAME
```

I have the above query, which I use in a pie chart.

However, because the information that this query grabs from has duplicate records I need to take the above query: (although I'm sure that the WHERE is wrong, because it lacks the appropriate expressions to finish the clause)

```
WHERE DISTINCT PO_PREFIX||PO_NUMBER||PO_SUFFIX
```

so as I do not double count the weights in the duplicate records

I've tried sub-queries, but I am currently a pretty big novice in SQL programming, and I don't think i did them correctly (can a SELECT DISTINCT column be used as a sub query?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets break the operations into steps,

**Step 1. Find all distinct rows:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   PO_PREFIX, PO_NUMBER, PO_SUFFIX, NET_WEIGHT,
   COALESCE(ORIGIN_NAME, 'Basket') AS ORIGIN
FROM 
   VW_PURCHASE_ORDER ;
```

**Step 2: Group by `origin`, using the above as a derived table (named `tmp`):**

```
SELECT
   ORIGIN, SUM(NET_WEIGHT) AS SUM_NET_WEIGHT
FROM
   ( SELECT DISTINCT 
        PO_PREFIX, PO_NUMBER, PO_SUFFIX, NET_WEIGHT,
        COALESCE(ORIGIN_NAME, 'Basket') AS ORIGIN
     FROM 
        VW_PURCHASE_ORDER 
   ) tmp
GROUP BY
   ORIGIN ;
```

Comment: good news is that absolutely worked...the bad news is, it doesn't work when i put it into the pie chart...but that is a problem for me to worry about

Comment: Clarification question. Is there a chance you have more than one rows with duplicate `PO_PREFIX, PO_NUMBER, PO_SUFFIX and ORIGIN_NAME` but different `NET_WEIGHT`? And what should be done in that case? (The above query adds them all, the different Net Weights).

Comment: No, if they have different net_weights then the problem lies with the people who inserted the data

Comment: ...well, i got it working, but the pie graph's numbers don't match up with the numbers retrieved in the query :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this will somewhat help you

```
SELECT TOP 1 ORIGIN_NAME, SUM(NET_WEIGHT),
CASE WHEN ORIGIN_NAME IS NULL THEN 'Basket' ELSE ORIGIN_NAME END AS ORIGIN
FROM VW_PURCHASE_ORDER
GROUP BY ORIGIN_NAME
```

Comment: i get a " "FROM keyword not found where expected"" (in the spot right after Top 1)

Comment: If the DBMS in use has not the `TOP` keyword, it will give error.

Comment: its okay in t-sql, so what is your RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to first select all the distinct rows and then make your group by. 
So this query might do what you need:

```
SELECT ORIGIN, SUM(NET_WEIGHT)
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT 
* ,
CASE WHEN ORIGIN_NAME IS NULL THEN 'Basket' ELSE ORIGIN_NAME END AS ORIGIN
FROM VW_PURCHASE_ORDER) AS QUERY
GROUP BY ORIGIN
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because ORIGIN_NAME isn't the same, I quote the OP: "I can't use distinct in the first select clause, because Origin_name cannot be distinct"

Comment: that is similar to what i tried (only i specified the DISTINCT column, if i distinct all the columns than my problem won't be solved [due to complicated record entries]) but i, like this code, recieved a "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: EDIT: i take it back, I can DISTINCT Origin_name

Comment: I see! so you shoul use the RANK function (in MYSQL SERVER) to only keep the fisrt tuple of PO_PREFIX||PO_NUMBER||PO_SUFFIX for each order ID, and the group by . Please try this `SELECT ORIGIN, SUM(NET_WEIGHT)
FROM (
SELECT 
  *, 
  CASE WHEN ORIGIN_NAME IS NULL THEN 'Basket' ELSE ORIGIN_NAME END AS ORIGIN
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID,PO_PREFIX,PO_NUMBER,PO_SUFFIX ORDER BY ID ORIGIN_NAME) AS Rank
FROM VW_PURCHASE_ORDER)

AS QUERY
WHERE RANK=1
GROUP BY ORIGIN`

Comment: `SELECT ORIGIN, SUM(NET_WEIGHT) FROM ( SELECT *, CASE WHEN ORIGIN_NAME IS NULL THEN 'Basket' ELSE ORIGIN_NAME END AS ORIGIN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID,PO_PREFIX,PO_NUMBER,PO_SUFFIX ORDER BY ORIGIN_NAME) AS Rank FROM VW_PURCHASE_ORDER) AS QUERY WHERE RANK=1 GROUP BY ORIGIN`